# PHP 5 MySQL ASCII error

Tags: php, mysql, ascii

I have a php script that I use to query my database with a like clause.

When I run the script I sometimes get an error that says this

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=8) state=0 in 
>   /ajax/rank_sidebar_1.php on line 33
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at 
>   /ajax/rank_sidebar_1.php:33) in  /ajax/rank_sidebar_1.php on line 2

What I don't get is that this never shows on my localhost sever but sometimes appear on my live server with godaddy.

On the godaddy server sometimes I can reload and it disappears.

Here's my php script

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){

  include '../connect.php';

  $uname = $_SESSION['user_name'];

  $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$uname'");
  $user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);

  $id = $user_row['id'];



 } else header('location: ../login.php');

if(isset($_GET['tab'])){

  $tab = $_GET['tab'];

 if($tab == 'draft'){

   $draft = 'Draft';

   $check_rank_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rankings WHERE user_id = '$id'
   AND ranking_type LIKE  '%{$draft}%'");



   while($rank_rows = mysql_fetch_array($check_rank_query)){

    $draft_ranks = $rank_rows['ranking'];

     $rank_id = $rank_rows['id'];

     if(preg_match('/Standard Rankings/', $draft_ranks)){

       echo '<li><a href="rank.php?   type=standard&tab=draft&pos=ov&id='.$rank_id.'">'.$draft_ranks.'</a></li>';

     } else if(preg_match('/STD Dynasty Rankings/', $draft_ranks)){

       echo '<li><a href="rank.php?type=std&tab=draft&pos=ov&id='.$rank_id.'">'.$draft_ranks.'</a></li>';

       }

     }



    }

  ?>
```

Comment: First of all - read this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: how will this help? @Jurik

Comment: I just can guess, but I think PDO will help you with character encoding.